# Timing attack in PHP

Tags: php, security

[strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) - what is means "Binary safe string comparison"? This compare is safe for the timing attack?

If no, how can I compare two strings for preventing the timing attack? Compare hashes of the strings is enough? Or I must use some library (or own code) that gives constant time for the compare?

[Here](http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/) writes that the timing attack can be used in the web. But can be this type of an attack exists in the real world? Or this attack can be used only for a small type of an attacker (like government) so this protection through the web is excess?

Comment: Well I think those attacks are real and can be done but it takes a long time to plan the attack, find the data you like to attack, etc.

I think most PHP scripts, or maybe PHP itself has bugs which are easier to exploit than to measure 5 days long to get an integer decrypted. But you should compare strings always with `===` and not with `==`.

Comment: We writes an app that catches callback from another app and gives a user some coins. This URL can be found by attacker so he can uses this url for the fraud coins receiving. These coins then can be withdrawn, so 5 day - it is a good scenario for the attacker )

There are some protection in our app, but I don't know must I use a timing attack protection or not

Comment: i think binary safe has nothing to do with timing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-safe

Comment: @Kyborek Nope it has not you're right. But I mentioned it just in case. Because it's also string comparision related stuff to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"binary safe" means that any bytes can be safely compared with `strcmp`, not just valid characters in some character set.  A quick test confirms that `strcmp` is not safe against timing attacks:

```
$nchars = 1000;
$s1 = str_repeat('a', $nchars + 1);
$s2 = str_repeat('a', $nchars) . 'b';
$s3 = 'b' . str_repeat('a', $nchars);

$times = 100000;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
    strcmp($s1, $s2);
}
$timeForSameAtStart = microtime(true) - $start;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
    strcmp($s1, $s3);
}
$timeForSameAtEnd = microtime(true) - $start;

printf("'b' at the end: %.4f\n'b' at the front: %.4f\n", $timeForSameAtStart, $timeForSameAtEnd);
```

For me this prints something like `'b' at the end: 0.0634 'b' at the front: 0.0287`.

Many other string-based functions in PHP likely suffer from similar issues.  Working around this is tricky, especially in PHP where you don't actually know what a lot of functions are really doing at the physical level.

One possible tactic is just sticking a random wait time in your code before you return the answer to the caller/potential attacker.  Even better, measure how long it took to check the input data (e.g., with `microtime`), and then wait a random time minus that amount of time.  This is not 100% secure, but it makes attacking the system MUCH harder because, at a minimum, an attacker will have to try each input many times in order to filter out the randomness.

Comment: For PHP 5.6, there's hash_equals(). For everything else, there's `$nonce = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); return hash_hmac('sha256', $calculated, $nonce) === hash_hmac('sha256', $expected, $nonce);`

Comment: instead of adding randomness that can be filtered out you could decide a minimum time the script has to execute, count the execution time and then wait the difference. If the execution is longer than expected you could wait for the next "chunk" of time. It's like "rounding" the execution time to 1 second, or 2 seconds if the real execution takes more than 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

The problem with strcmp is, that it depends on implementation. If it binarily compares each byte of strings until it reaches difference or end of either strings, then it is vulnerable to timing attack.

**Now how about hashing?**

I have found this Security question and i belive it has the correct answer for you: 
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46215

Answer (score -4):

Timing attack is a myth.

I explain.

The time that it takes to validates a text, between one similar versus other different is around a fraction of second, let's say +/- 0.1 second (exaggerated!).

However, the time that it takes an attacker to measure this time is:

delay of the network + 0.1 seconds + delay of the system (may be its busy doing some other task) + other delays.

So no, its not possible, even for a local system (lag zero), the result of interval of time is always unclear.

In a test, let's say the difference between one method and another is 1us.

So, if we test it and the difference is 1us, then we could guess part of the number.

But what if there is another factor, for example, the network, the cpu usage at the moment, the cpu cycle of the moment and such.

Even if we excluded the network, we have that most operating systems are multi-tasking, so the test must be done in a system with a single-tasking operating system or a system running a single task, and that is not something that you see in the wild. Even embedded systems run multiple threads at the same time.

But let's say we run locally (not network) and we are doing a drill-run in a computer that only runs a single task, our task.   But we have another problem, modern CPUs don't run at a constant cycle, they vary depending on the usage (, temperature and other factors.

So, it is only possible if:

- it is executed locally and there is no other factor.
- it runs as a single task and no other task is running on the server.
- the cpu runs constantly.

i.e. it is ABSURD.

### it is the test.

```php
<?php
$text='123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234';
$compare1='12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123x';
$compare2='2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222';

$a1=microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    if($compare1===$text) {
        // do something
    }
}
$a2=microtime(true);
var_dump($a2-$a1);

$a1=microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    if($compare2===$text) {
        // do something
    }
}


$a2=microtime(true);
var_dump($a2-$a1);
```

It took me 5 minutes to invalidate this hypothesis.

What is tested:

- it tests a 512bit  text and it compares with two tests and compares the times.
- This test is done to prove the hypothesis so it forces a no-real situation where the first text compared is almost the same as the first test (excluding the last character).
- It also excludes latencies and other operations.
- (why 512bits, most passwords are encrypted in 128 and 256bits, 512bits is what we can call it safe)

And it is the result.

one round:

- 0.021588087081909
- 0.021672010421753 (long time)

another run:

- 0.021767854690552
- 0.022729873657227 (long time)

and another run:

- 0.021697998046875 (long time)
- 0.021611213684082

and again

- 0.021565914154053 (long time)
- 0.020948171615601

and again

- 0.021995067596436
- 0.0224769115448 (long time)

So, even when the test is forced to validate the point, it fails.

i.e.
you can't find a trend when one of the variables is unknown and this factor compromises the whole test.   I can test it 1 million times and the result will be the same.  And this test, in particular, avoids any variable such as latency, other processes, access to the database, etc.

Comment: Such jitter becomes negligible when averaged across the 100,000s of tests they run to check timing down to an accuracy of 20us across the internet and 100ns across a lan. https://www.cs.rice.edu/~dwallach/pub/crosby-timing2009.pdf

Comment: True if the test ignore the latency of the network, the use of the cpu to read such information, the transportation of this information, the process of such program and only if (and only if), the system is only running a SINGLE OPERATION, i.e. we are not running a multitasking OS or different threads or processes.

i.e. it is IMPOSSIBLE, no matter if it is testes 1 time or 1 million times.

Math speaking: Delta Expected = Delta Operation + X

Where X is a factor caused by an external operation.

Comment: See section 6.6 of the linked research, where they discuss a loaded Apache server introducing a net average of only 1us of jitter with only 1000 tests, which is substantially less that the other jitter over the internet. They also state how they avoided connection startup jitter as an attacker would do.  Do you have any research that corroborates you statements?

Comment: What Patanjali says is correct. I would point out though that if you are allowing enough requests to allow an attacker to carry out 100,000's of tests (or even a small fraction of this), you have more vulnerabilities than just a timing attack. Best practice is to shut someone out after a small number of guesses, and do it both by IP and by whatever information was requested (login, email validation, etc.) Some botnets have hundreds of thousands of boxes and may carry out only one request from each IP. But using abuse lists can protect against a huge portion of these. Use multiple measures!

Comment: @Patanjali  well yes, I added the test that empirically shows that IT IS IMPOSSIBLE to do a timing attack using a comparison of a string.

Comment: I agree with @magallanes answer in it's current form and it's unlucky that it got voted down for it's previous version(s).
Also: I did not run the tests myself, but I would go so far as to assume that the difference in runtime wouldn't even be noticable if the strings tested woud be of different sizes.